# PHP in_array() does not find content that is in an array

Tags: php, arrays

i have a very simple script that reads out a txt file, puts the content in an array.

Which does perfectly, i can do `print_r($array)`; and it outputs all the data.

My script:

```
<?php

$file = 'countries.txt';
$countries_output = file_get_contents($file);

$countries_pieces = explode("\n", $countries_output);

if (in_array("Sweden", $countries_pieces)) {
   echo "Sweden was found";
}
else 
{
echo'NOT FOUND';
}
print_r($countries_pieces);
?>
```

I don't understand why it doesn't find the value 'Sweden' in my array, when it clearly is in there.

This is the output: https://pastebin.com/z9rC9Qvk

I also print_r the array, so you can see that 'Sweden' is indeed in the array.

Hope someone can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is countries.txt from a Windows machine? If so, splitting on '\n' won't work very well since there's also a '\r' for every line.

Your print_r output would seem to indicate that since there seems to be an extra newline between every line of output.

Answer (score 9):

There is most likely new line characters that you're not taking into account.  The following is a cleaner solution using [`file()`](http://php.net/file) and should work for you:

```
$file = 'countries.txt';
$countries_pieces = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

if (in_array("Sweden", $countries_pieces)) {
   echo "Sweden was found";
} else {
    echo'NOT FOUND';
}
```

If there are still some issues, a common normalization is to [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) values to remove some left-overs:

```
$countries_pieces = array_map('trim', $countries_pieces);
```

But this must not cure all issues.

Comment: Yup - there's probably still a \r, or some other weirdness there.

Comment: @Godius:  Remember to mark the question as answered if the answer solved your issue.